# Simulate data for regression with standardized Y

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, simulation, linear-regression

Based on [this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59062/multiple-linear-regression-simulation), I have created a function that returns a dataset with variables related to the outcome (`y`) by specific linear coefs.

```
simulate_data_regression <- function(sample=10, coefs=0, error=0){

  n_var <- length(coefs)
  X <- matrix(0, ncol=n_var, nrow=sample)

  beta <- as.matrix(coefs)

  for (i in 1:n_var){
    X[,i] <- scale(rnorm(sample, 0, 1))
  }

  y <- X %*% beta

  if(error != 0){
    y <- y + rnorm(sample, 0, error)
  }


  data = data.frame(X=X)
  names(data) <- paste0("V", 1:n_var)
  data$y <- as.vector(y)

  return(data)
}

data <- simulate_data_regression(sample=50, coefs=c(0.1, 0.8), error=0)
summary(data)
sd(data$V1)
sd(data$y)
```

It works great. However, I would need to have a standardized `y` (mean 0 and SD 1). But when I try to scale it, the coefficients change:

```
data <- simulate_data_regression(sample=50, coefs=c(0.1, 0.8), error=0)
data$y <- as.vector(scale(data$y))
coef(lm(y ~ ., data=data))
```

It is possible to do such thing? Thank you very much!

---

## Edit

In other words, I would like the coefs that are specified to be standardized coefs (expressed in outcome's SD).

Scaling `y` a posteriori changes the coefs by `1/sd(y)`. However, I can't think of any way to change the betas before generating y, so that the betas return to their specified value after the scaling of `y`.

---

## Edit 2: Failed attempt

I've tried running the function twice, first extracting `sd(y)` and scaling the coefficients with it, in the hope that those scaled coefficients will change to the specified ones once I'll scale `y`. But it doens't work, which is expected, as `sd(y)` changes when I change the coefs :'(

Here's the failed attempt:

```
simulate_data_regression <- function(sample=10, coefs=0, error=0, standardized=TRUE){

  stuff <- .simulate_data_regression(sample=sample, coefs=coefs, error=error)
  if(standardized == TRUE){
    y_sd <- sd(data$y)
    data <- .simulate_data_regression(sample=sample, coefs=y_sd*coefs, error=error, X=stuff$X)$data
    data$y <- as.vector(scale(data$y))
  } else{
    data <- stuff$data
  }
  return(data)
}


.simulate_data_regression <- function(sample=10, coefs=0, error=0, X=NULL, y=NULL){

  n_var <- length(coefs)

  if(is.null(X)){
    X <- matrix(0, ncol=n_var, nrow=sample)
    for (i in 1:n_var){
      X[,i] <- scale(rnorm(sample, 0, 1))
    }
  }

  beta <- as.matrix(coefs)
  y <- X %*% beta

  if(error != 0){
    y <- y + rnorm(sample, 0, error)
  }


  data = data.frame(X=X)
  names(data) <- paste0("V", 1:n_var)
  data$y <- as.vector(y)

  return(list(X=X, y=y, data=data))
}
```

Comment: If you want to get the same coefficients you need to call `scale(y, scale = FALSE)`. The betas are invariant to location so you can center at will. But they are not invariant to scaling, if you scale `x1` by a factor then `beta1` will be multiplied by `1/factor1`.

Comment: It's something, but the scaling of y is actually what I would need the most (so that the specified coefs are in fact standardized coefs)... Is there any way of generating this kind of data?

Answer (score 2):

If you scale `y` the inference will be the same, only the p-values of the intercepts change, not the p-values of the coefficients.
In this example I have set `error = 1`.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible
data <- simulate_data_regression(sample = 50, coefs = c(0.1, 0.8), error = 1)
data2 <- data
data2$y <- scale(data2$y)

fit <- lm(y ~ ., data)
fit2 <- lm(y ~ ., data2)

summary(fit)
summary(fit2)
```

As you can see the p-values of the coefficients are exactly the same though the coefficients themselves are different. You would expect that since you are scaling by the standard errors of the regressors and therefore the coefficients will be scaled by the inverses of those standard errors.

The version of your function below has an argument, `which`, that allows to specify which regressors to scale. Its default is all of them.

```
simulate_data_regression2 <- function(sample = 10, coefs = 0, error = 0, which = seq_along(coefs)){
  n_var <- length(coefs)
  X <- matrix(0, ncol=n_var, nrow=sample)
  beta <- as.matrix(coefs)
  for (i in 1:n_var){
    X[,i] <- rnorm(sample, 0, 1)
    if(i %in% which) X[, i] <- scale(X[, i])
  }
  y <- X %*% beta
  if(error != 0){
    y <- y + rnorm(sample, 0, error)
  }
  data = data.frame(X=X)
  names(data) <- paste0("V", 1:n_var)
  data$y <- as.vector(y)
  data
}
```

Now test the function.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible
data <- simulate_data_regression2(sample=50, coefs=c(0.1, 0.8), error=1)

set.seed(1234)    # Reproduce the data generation process
data2 <- simulate_data_regression2(sample=50, coefs=c(0.1, 0.8), error=1, which = 2)

fit <- lm(y ~ ., data)
fit2 <- lm(y ~ ., data2)
```

As you can see the coefficients of `V2` are equal.

```
coef(fit)
#(Intercept)          V1          V2 
# 0.01997809  0.19851020  0.96310013

coef(fit2)
#(Intercept)          V1          V2 
# 0.07040538  0.21130549  0.96310013
```

The p-values of the estimates of the coefficients `V2` are also equal

```
summary(fit)
summary(fit2)
```

Comment: Since coefficients are scaled by `1/sd(y)`. Isn't it a way to reverse-engineer this so that the coefficients that I specify, and that I wand at the end, are the ones scaled?

Comment: You would have to change the function. Have an argument tell which regressors you want to scale.

Comment: @DominiqueMakowski Done, see if this is it.

Comment: I got happy too fast, in fact if I run your function, `y` is not scaled, and the coefficients do not refer to 1 SD of y. But if I scale `y`, it changes the coefs...

Comment: @DominiqueMakowski No, `y` is not scaled, if you look at the first code, in line 4 I scale `y` outside *your* function. In the second example I haven't. If you scale `y` the coefficients will change but not the p-values, the inference is the same.

Comment: I understand that inference is the same, it's just that I need to create standardized regression data with specific standardized coefficients (I don't really care about the inference, only the coefs)... I think my post wasn't explicit enough, maybe I should rewrite it

Comment: @DominiqueMakowski If that's what you need, use the function passing which regressors you need to standardize in argument `which`. And standardize the response outside the function. This latter is easily done, it's just one variable.

Comment: Unfortunately when I try: `data <- simulate_data_regression2(sample=50, coefs=c(0, 0.5), error=0, which = seq_along(coefs))` (your function with `which` by default, *i.e.* all coefs) and then `data$y <- as.vector(scale(y))`, I expect that the resulting coefficients will be 0 and 0.5, but `coef(lm(y ~ ., data=data))` returns unexpected coefs